# List<T> - distinction by T.field

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `List<X>` where `X` has a couple of fields:

```
public string word;
public int count;
```

how do I get a `List<X>` with distinct `X.word` elements?

Comment: I don't know how important it is for you to use a List and whether performance is an issue. If SortedList would do you could define a comparison operator for X which uses lexicographical odering for the string ( X < Y iff X.word < Y.word ). You can then use binary search to check whether an entry with given X.word already exists and insert only if not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use grouping

```
var n = from n in items
    group n by n.word into g
    select g.First();
```

Answer (score 2):

[MoreLinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) has a `DistinctBy` method:

```
var distinctByWord = list.DistinctBy(x => x.Word).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

From your data structure, I'd suggest you probably want a Dictionary instead of a list.

If you are doing something like counting the number of times a word is seen, or even combining (word,count) pairs from some other input by adding the counts, it will be more efficient to do this with a Dictionary because you won't have to scan the list to find the entry to update.

Comment: +1 for pointing that out, however, a more complete answer would also have included how to do it in case a dictionary is not what he wants.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use the overload of the [Distinct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx) method that takes an instance of `IEqualityComparer<X>`:

```
new List<X>().Distinct(new XComparer());

public class XComparer : IEqualityComparer<X> {
    public bool Equals(X x, X y) {
        return x.word.Equals(y.word);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(X obj) {
        return obj.word.GetHashCode();
    }
}

public class X {
    public string Word { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

And then:

```
var myList = new List<X>() { 
    new X(){ Count = 1, Word = "A" }, 
    new X(){ Count = 2, Word = "A"}, 
    new X(){ Count = 1, Word = "B"} 
};

foreach(var x in myList.Distinct(new XComparer()))
    Console.WriteLine(x.Count + " " + x.Word);
```

Prints:

```
1  A
1  B
```

Comment: this returns a `List<string>`, not a `List<X>`

Answer (score 0):

I think the idea is to count the words and not to lose counts for words with the same name, right? If so, it reminds me map-reduce algorithm. You have already done map, so you need to do reduce somehow. I recommend you to create new `Dictionary<string,int>` and loop your list. If Dictionary does not have word - add it (key - word, count - value), if has - add count to value.